# How to add second value to dictionary key from list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I'm trying to create a dictionary from a list containing tuples (n1, n2). To do so, I wrote a functions which takes as argument that list and returns dictionary {'n1': {'n2'}, etc.} The problem I encountered with it is when list contains multiple tuples with the same key (n1) but different value (n2). Mainly, the else statement seems to not work and I am not sure why.

```
def construction_dict_amis(f_lst):
    """builds and returns a dictionary of people (keys) who declare all their friends (as values)
    f_lst: couple list(n1, n2): n1 has friend n2
    if n1 has more than 1 friend add another name to that key
    if for the couple (n1, n2) n2 does not declare any friends an empty set will be created
    """
    f = {}
    for n1, n2 in f_lst:
        if n1 not in n2:
            f[n1] = {n2}
        else:
            f[n1].extend(n2) #add n2 to n1 if n1 already present ?
        if n2 not in f:
            f[n2] = set()  # new entry first name2
    return f

print(construction_dict_amis([('Mike', 'Peter'),('Thomas', 'Michelle'),('Thomas', 'Peter')]))
```

expected output:

```
{'Mike' : {'Peter'}, 'Peter' : set(), 'Thomas' : {'Michelle', 'Peter'}, 'Michelle' : set()}
```

actual output:

```
{'Mike': {'Peter'}, 'Peter': set(), 'Thomas': {'Peter'}, 'Michelle': set()}
```

Comment: I would expect to get `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'extend'`. Did you mean `.add`? Also note you seem to be mixing up `f`, `n1` and `n2` - perhaps more descriptive names would help.

Comment: `{n2}` creates a `set`, not a dict or a list. As per the above comment, use `.add(n2)` to add `n2` to the set.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank you for your comment.  I did not receive that error and yes I tried .add and obtained the same result, that us, Thomas is listed just with Peter.

Comment: I think you mean `n1 not in f`, i.e. if the first person in the tuple isn't already in the dictionary, rather than `n1 not in n2`. Also I don't understand the logic behind adding the second person's name to the dictionary but not the fact they're linked to the first person.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes that is my mistake. Thank you!

Comment: I must have n1 not in f and use .add. Thank you again everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a beautiful dictionary method called [setdefault](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-setdefault-method/) which is exactly what you want:

```
def construction_dict_amis(f_lst):
    f = {}
    for n1, n2 in f_lst:
        f.setdefault(n1, set()).add(n2) # Initiate friends of n1 if not initialized, and add n2 as friend
        f.setdefault(n2, set())         # Initiate firends of n2 if not initialized, and leave unchanged
    return f
```

Comment: Thanks @Amitai Irron, that looks much simpler indeed.